Circuit to handle multiple PSU input options
I'm trying to design a simple circuit that can handle different power supply sources for my microcontroller project.
The microcontroller and its associated circuitry need 3.3V, and additionally I need a voltage equal or greater than 5V to power a pair of op-amps that need a little bit more that 3.3V (those op-amps will probably be LM324 and will follow the 3.3V DAC to raise its output voltage a little bit).
The possible voltage inputs could be:

USB (probably a USB-C connector), other that providing supply, USB will be used for USB-device capabilities.
an external +9V DC power adapter
an external Eurorack PSU (essentially a bipolar +12/-12V PSU that usually connects to the PCB using a connector like this). The negative voltage will be ignored by my PCB.

I don't expect the +9V PSU and the +12V PSU to be both used at the same time, so I guess I can skip the needed protection to avoid that situation, hence we can assume that +9V pin and +12V pin would be a common node on my PCB.
What I'm trying to understand is how I can make sure that the PCB can be powered by USB only, or by +9V/+12V only, or by +9V/+12V in the case both USB and external power is applied?
I've seen some approaches on various Arduino boards and derivatives, but they are probably too complex for my situation, where I don't need a regulated 5V supply nor USB host support.
I'm wondering if I can only use MOSFETs and passives. Since this will be a PCB built and assembled in quantities, I'm trying to avoid pricey and less common ICs.
And how much more difficult it gets if I want to be sure that connecting both +9V and +12V won't damage the PCB or the connected PSUs?


I think the simplest solution is two or three diodes (like a diode-OR gate)... and then whatever is the highest of the input voltages will go to the >=5V rail and the 3.3V regulator. The 1N5819 is my go-to for stuff <= 1A of current. If you need more current just get a beefier diode, or put multiple diodes in parallel.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
EDIT: If you have USB only, the diode drop will reduce the voltage to 4.8V or less depending on the diode. Keep that in mind.
